# Can a landlord return to live in his property together with an overholding tenant?

Tags: rental-property, landlord, florida

If the landlord has a month to month lease with a tenant and the the landlord decided to terminate the lease, but the tenant ignores and overstays. 
Does the landlord has a right to enter the property and live there together with the tenant?

Answer (score 1):

### Generally not

Specifics differ by jurisdiction but while the tenant was still in possession (even unlawfully), the landlord has very limited rights to the property. The landlord would need to legally evict a squatting tenant before they could resume their property rights.

Comment: Do you know about Florida, Hillsborough county?

Comment: Also what could happen to me if I do that?

Comment: I'm also curious: This answer suggests that there's a difference between a squatter who was once a legitimate tenant and a squatter who was not?

Comment: I disconnected the internet in the house but I need to get the modem back to the store. Do I have the right to enter the house to take it after notifying the tenant?